# How to seek through a stream with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, stream, file-get-contents

I'm using PHP to run a webservice. One of the url need to get couple images from the POST body. I currently using a fopen/fread solution :

```
$size1 = intval($_REQUEST['img1']);
$size2 = intval($_REQUEST['img2']);
$sizeToRead = 4096;
$datas1 = null;
$datas2 = null;

$h = fopen('php://input','r+');
while($size1 > 0) {
    if($sizeToRead > $size1)
        $sizeToRead = $size1;

    $datas1 .= fread($h,$sizeToRead);
    $size1 -= $sizeToRead;
}
fclose($h);

file_put_contents('received1.png',$datas1);
//Same thing for the second image
```

This solution works fine , but i'm trying to make it more readable by using `file_get_contents()` :

```
file_put_contents('received1.png',file_get_contents('php://input',false,null,0,$size1));
```

But it's give me an error :

> file_get_contents() stream does not support seeking
>   file_get_contents() Failed to seek to position 21694 in the stream

Is that even possible to seek in a stream ? Maybe by changing the third parameter to something else ?

If not , is there way to make my code more elegant / efficient ?

Thanks.

Comment: How is file_get_contents() going to make anything more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> Note: A stream opened with php://input can only be read once; **the stream does not support seek operations**. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

(my emphasis)